# Design pattern for different formats

Tags: design-patterns

I have a requirement where i need to output data in given format (can be anything xml, json, doc, csv, xls, signed xml) etc. After that I need to wrap it in given format (zip, gzip, cab, etc). What would be good design pattern for it?

Answer (score 0):

For formatting the output data and for wrapping the data I'd recommend the [strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). You could have an interface like `DataFormatterInterface` with implementations like `XmlDataFormatter` etc. Same for wrapping where you'll have a `DataWrapperInterface` with concretions as `ZipDataWrapper`.

Then as you'll always be using the same two steps you could give the [template method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) pattern a shot if you have the need to abstract this even more. This will allow you to write an interface like `DataExporterInterface` and implementations like `GzippedCsvExporter`